# What is the PPA for ubuntustudio-installer

Tags: apt, ppa, ubuntu-studio

**Backstory:**

I have installed Ubuntu and tried to install Ubuntu Studio on top of it. But, that didn't seem to work. So, I replaced the distro with the actual Ubuntu Studio distro. Unfortunately, I can't get used to how fugly the entire environment is, along with all of the missing keyboard shortcuts. So, I'm back to trying to install Ubunto Studio on top of Ubuntu.

**Problem:**

When I run `sudo apt install ubuntustudio-installer`, I just get an error saying that that package isn't found.

**What I've done:**

I've tried adding the backport PPA. I've tried clearing the PPA cache. However, since it's a fresh installation, I can't imagine that being the issue. I've searched online for others with the same issue. However, there isn't a single page that I have found anyone else trying to install it this way. I've seen others recommend installing it this way, but it seems like no one else seems to have a problem installing it. Is there something I'm missing?

Can someone help me get this installed on top of a regular Ubuntu distro?

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Which media was used for its installation?

Comment: It's not found in any PPA; but in standard 'universe' repository; 'universe' being the community supported repository where all *flavor* packages are found.  A new Ubuntu install does not add have 'universe' enabled as all 'main' packages provided by default have 5 years of support; that cannot be said for 'universe' which has variable; from 9 months to 3 years at longest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This package is available from *universe* [pocket](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=ubuntustudio-installer):

```
sudo apt-add-repository universe
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-installer
```

---

For Ubuntu 20.04 LTS you can also use [PPA `ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eubuntustudio-ppa/+archive/ubuntu/backports?field.series_filter=focal) and commands below:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ubuntustudio-installer
```

Removing this PPA is possible by

```
sudo apt install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ubuntustudio-ppa/backports
```

Comment: Yeah, that was it. I didn't have `universe` added.